# How to run windows 10 kiosk mode with 2 screens?

Tags: windows-10

I want to have 1 browser instance open on each screen on windows 10 kiosk mode preferable using chrome

Answer (score 1):

Even the question is too wide to understand, you can use "Project" property of windows 10 and then select repeat for two screens.
[image]

Comment: where do i find this Project propety?

Comment: I added the SS.

Comment: You can navigate to bottom right of task bar, or you can search in settings for project.